# What is the correct word for someone rotating into a rotation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, nouns

We have people at work rotating into our group through a rotation program.  I call the people rotating in/out "rotatees" but MS Word and apparently StackExchange puts red squigglies underneath that word so I'm wondering what is the correct word for someone rotating in and out of our group in a professional, work sense.

They have their feature team that they work with but for now, all new employees under 1 yr exp with the company come thru our team to learn some debugging and routing skills for a 6 week period. I don't know think they see themselves as a separate identifiable group when they come into my team, they just see themselves as serving time with us for 6 wks before they go back to what they were hired to do.

Comment: MS Word and other spell checkers often put squiggly red lines under words that are in fact recognized words (like [qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit), e.g.). A good place to check is [OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=rotatee&ls=a).

Answer (score 4):

"Rotatee" has some usage. In the armed forces, soldiers are "rotated" out of combat duty, such people are called rotatees.

However, the amount of use is very low, and most dictionaries have not picked up the word (perhaps because it is a common misspelling of "rotates")

So you can go on using "rotatees" (if everybody on your team now understands the term). It might be a bit company jargon but that is okay. Or you can use a longer descriptive phrase such as "colleagues who have joined the team on rotation", or "short term team members" (there are lots of possibilities)

Answer (score 1):

You could call them "*temporary assignees*"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the word **shift**.

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shift), definition #2 as a noun:

> 2.
>   a. A group of workers that relieve another on a regular schedule.
>
> b. The working period of such a group: worked the night shift.

Comment: From my understanding of the question, these aren't shift-workers. They are workers who are moved from one team to another, perhaps to gain experience of the range of jobs within the company.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps call them ***peripatetic*** workers.

> **peripatetic** *- travelling from place to place, in particular **working or based in various places for relatively short periods*** <sub>[Oxford Dictionary of English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1322&lpg=PA1322&dq=define%20peripatetic%20%22travelling%20from%20place%20to%20place,%20in%20particular%20working%20or%20based%20in%20various%20places%22&source=bl&ots=T_iueriIxN&sig=ACfU3U1LzrH__aZGXGM6vyg5q8tGlhoXhg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwgPGxjYzjAhV1unEKHcvlB0QQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20peripatetic%20%22travelling%20from%20place%20to%20place%2C%20in%20particular%20working%20or%20based%20in%20various%20places%22&f=false)</sub>

Comment: This doesn't fit with my understanding of the question - peripatetic specifically refers to locational-moves, not organisational moves. Personally, I would make "rotated-in" fit somehow, unless there was a more specific term that fits - this sort of scheme is often used with new graduates, for example.

Comment: Even if only 1% of all references to ***peripatetic workers*** were the more metaphorical sense of moving between *organisational departments* rather than *physical locations*, I reckon that would still be far more than all the references to our front-runner ***rotatees*** here! :)